Uncertainty of mean
Assume I have $N$ measurements, each with error estimate $\delta$, i.e., $x_1\pm\delta,x_2\pm\delta,\dots,x_N\pm\delta$. What is the best way to estimate the error of the mean value $(x_1+x_2+\dots +x_N)/N$? Do I need to apply the standard error of the mean (SEM) somehow?
Update: To be more precise about my case, I have estimated a probability for every pixel in a grid using Monte Carlo simulations. Now I want to estimate the average probability (total probability) in certain regions of my grid. $x_i$ is the different pixels in the region of interest and $\delta$ is given by the number of Monte Carlo iterations.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you already have a margin of error? I think that will be a good starting point.

The "error estimate" - what is that? Is is quantified in terms of a standard deviation, perhaps?

Ok, to be more precise about my case. I have estimated a probability for every pixel in a grid using Monte Carlo simulations. Now I want to estimate the average probability (total probability) in certain regions of my grid. $x_i$ is the different pixels in the region of interest and $\delta$ is given by the number of Monte Carlo iterations.

To estimate the mean you will need to understand the covariance structure of your different measurements. Assuming the measurements are not independent, I would calculate the desired mean and estimate its standard error using direct results from the simulation
